# Would like to see list of deselected tests and their node ids in pytest output

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Is there an option to list the deselected tests in the cli output along with the mark that triggered their deselection?

I know that in suites with many tests this would not be good as a default but would be a useful option in something like api testing where the tests are likely to be more limited.

The numeric summary

```
collected 21 items / 16 deselected / 5 selected
```

is helpful but not enough when trying to organize marks and see what happened in a ci build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pytest` has a hookspec [`pytest_deselected`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_deselected) for accessing the deselected tests. Example: add this code to `conftest.py` in your test root dir:

```
def pytest_deselected(items):
    if not items:
        return
    config = items[0].session.config
    reporter = config.pluginmanager.getplugin("terminalreporter")
    reporter.ensure_newline()
    for item in items:
        reporter.line(f"deselected: {item.nodeid}", yellow=True, bold=True)
```

Running the tests now will give you an output similar to this:

```
$ pytest -vv
...
plugins: cov-2.8.1, asyncio-0.10.0
collecting ...
deselected: test_spam.py::test_spam
deselected: test_spam.py::test_bacon
deselected: test_spam.py::test_ham
collected 4 items / 3 deselected / 1 selected
...
```

If you want a report in another format, simply store the deselected items in the config and use them for the desired output somewhere else, e.g. `pytest_terminal_summary`:

```
# conftest.py

import os

def pytest_deselected(items):
    if not items:
        return
    config = items[0].session.config
    config.deselected = items


def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    reports = terminalreporter.getreports('')
    content = os.linesep.join(text for report in reports for secname, text in report.sections)
    deselected = getattr(config, "deselected", [])
    if deselected:
        terminalreporter.ensure_newline()
        terminalreporter.section('Deselected tests', sep='-', yellow=True, bold=True)
        content = os.linesep.join(item.nodeid for item in deselected)
        terminalreporter.line(content)
```

gives the output:

```
$ pytest -vv
...
plugins: cov-2.8.1, asyncio-0.10.0
collected 4 items / 3 deselected / 1 selected                                                     

...

---------------------------------------- Deselected tests -----------------------------------------
test_spam.py::test_spam
test_spam.py::test_bacon
test_spam.py::test_ham
================================= 1 passed, 3 deselected in 0.01s =================================
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!